# SQL to spilt a large table by row numbers into new tables

Tags: sql

I have a very large SQL table of  2 million records,

I want to get different tables of 200000 rows each from the large table without overlapping records

Please help with the script

Comment: 2 milions records is not so much. What's a real motivation to move some data into another table?

Comment: Any database (even H2) is able to handle 2 million rows, no sweat. Don't split them.

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server? They're not the same database products.

Comment: As other comments have indicated, you probably don't want to actually do this (separate your table into multiple, arbitrary tables). However, you might want to look into "partitioning" your table if you have concerns about the size eventually affecting performance (this still acts as one table). If you have specific concerns about performance currently, you could post an actual query that you're having trouble with, the current table indexes, and an explain plan.

Comment: Thanks for your swift attention.
I need to reduce the  records to enable Me download of the splited table into Excel for further analysis

Comment: You can use queries for that. You don't need to literally make it a separate table. How are you downloading it? What's the name of your primary key?